# Spring Data REST - Consume List of Entities, Java HATEOAS client

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Data REST 2.5.1, Jackson 2.8.0, Spring Boot 1.3.6.

I'm trying to retrieve a simple list of entities from my Repository via RestTemplate. I can hit the end point in a browser, and get the expected HAL data. Retrieving a single Entity works fine as below. These are all using the default SDR endpoints (e.g. localhost:{port}/myEntity).

```
    ResponseEntity<Resource<MyEntity>> responseEntity =
    new RestTemplate()
        .exchange(
        uri + "/1",
            HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpEntity.EMPTY,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<MyEntity>>() {}, port
        )
```

Or
    new RestTemplate().getForEntity(uri + "/1", MyEntity.class, port)

As a lot of SO questions seem to indicate, finding examples of retrieving a list is a problem. I've tried the `ParameterizedTypeReference` with `Resources`,`Resource`, `MyEntity`, an array, List. All with no luck.

```
        ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<MyEntity>>> responseEntity =
            new RestTemplate()
                    .exchange(
                    uri,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    HttpEntity.EMPTY,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<MyEntity>>>() {}
            , port
            )
```

When called like above with pretty much any variety of `Resources`, `Resource`, `List<MyEntity>`, `MyEntity`, etc., the `ResponseEntity` is empty. Like:

```
<200 OK,Resources { content: [], links: [] },{Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[...]}>
```

The string JSON looks like below in browser.

```
{
"_embedded" : {
"myEntities" : [ ... ]
},
"_links" : {
"self" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/myEntity"
},
"profile" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/myEntity"
},
"search" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/myEntity/search"
}
},
"page" : {
  "size" : 20,
  "totalElements" : 10,
  "totalPages" : 1,
  "number" : 1
 }
}
```

Repository Definition:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "myEntities", path = "myEntity")
public interface MyEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Long>
, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity>
, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QMyEntity> { }
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Comment: If you look at the structure of `Resources` you will notice that it's different from the structure of the JSON document. It's like trying to open your house with your car key.

Comment: Yeah, I get that the way I'm trying isn't working. I'm trying to find out what does work, not what doesn't.

If SDR is creating this format, there has to be a Spring class that expects to consume it. I shouldn't have to roll my own for its standard format.

Comment: The basis for the document in your example is `PagedResources`. `_embedded` relies on `EmbeddedWrapper`. But there is no class that directly represents the document. The document is built dynamically because the `_embedded` property is dynamic.

Comment: I added the example repository definition. I get that it is a `PagedResource` because I'm extending the `PagingAndSortingRepository`, but is there no support for Java clients? I'm not doing anything specific to create an `_embedded` section. This is what SDR is giving me by default. Do I need to create a MyEntityResource?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this by doing a few things.

1. I had to update to spring-hateoas:0.20.0.RELEASE from 0.19.0. spring-hateoas:0.19.0 did not support jackson 2.7+ as specified [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5758).
2. I updated my Client to call as below.

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = builder.build()
   MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

   messageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/hal+json"))
   messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper)

   ResponseEntity<PagedResources<MyEntity>> responseEntity =
           new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(messageConverter))
                   .exchange(
                   uri,
                   HttpMethod.GET,
                   HttpEntity.EMPTY,
                   new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<MyEntity>>() {}, port
           )
   ```

PagedResources now looks like this:

```
<200 OK,PagedResource { content: [{<List of MyEntities>}], metadata: Metadata { number: 0, total pages: 1, total elements: 10, size: 20 }, links: [<List of hateoas links for MyEntities>] },{Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Content-Type=[application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Thu, 21 Jul 2016 14:57:18 GMT]}>
```

@zeroflagL's comment got me looking more closely at the PagedResources implementation, which eventually led to the 'aha!' moment with this [blog](https://izeye.blogspot.com/2015/01/consume-spring-data-rest-hateoas-hal.html).

The relevant bit is that the default `RestTemplate` doesn't set the accept header to `application/hal+json`. Instead, the default is `application/x-spring-data-compact+json;charset=UTF-8` which has not content and only links. This is why I was getting empty content for my `Resources` types. Explicitly setting the MediaType as above fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
    ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<EntityObject>> responseType;
    responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<EntityObject>>() { };

    ResponseEntity<PagedResources<EntityObject>> pageResources;
    pageResources = restTemplate
            .withBasicAuth(username, password)
            .exchange(
                    UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/your/api/path").build().toString(),
                    GET,
                    null,
                    responseType
            );

    PagedResources<EntityObject> resource = pageResources.getBody();
    assertTrue(resource.getContent().isEmpty());
```

Comment: This approach worked for me in spring-hateoas/0.25.1.RELEASE (org.springframework.boot 2.1.3.RELEASE), which appears to use "application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8" as the content-type. Also, I'm using TestRestTemplate, since this is for a test case, but I'm not sure if that matters or not.