# Spring Data Rest testing

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I'm developing the application by using Spring Data Rest. As you know, after creating simple repository interfaces, rest-endpoints are created by library.

Do I need to test these endpoints by integration tests? If yes, please provide any examples

Comment: Yes, I think you should definitely write tests.
you can find examples  [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)

Comment: Yes, you can test them with MockMVC

Answer (score 1):

here is the code snippet. read the full tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String name;

    // standard getters and setters, constructors
}

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    public Employee findByName(String name);
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
  SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,
  classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(
  locations = "classpath:application-integrationtest.properties")
public class EmployeeRestControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repository;

    @Test
public void givenEmployees_whenGetEmployees_thenStatus200()
  throws Exception {

    createTestEmployee("bob");

    mvc.perform(get("/api/employees")
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(content()
      .contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("bob")));
}
}
```

Comment: Isn't there an automated way of generating the tests that verifies all endpoints like the fact that @RepositoryRestResource generates all endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from regular testing you can do with Spring (using MockMvc, RestAssured, RestTemplate etc), [Traverson](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#client.traverson) is a great API for specifically testing Spring HATEOAS. You can use it to test the validity of the links you are returning to your clients, see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41674139/3271729)

Answer (score 0):

With https://github.com/Cosium/hal-mock-mvc, you can test them as follow:

```java
   @AutoConfigureHalMockMvc
   @SpringBootTest
   class MyTest {
     @Autowired
     private HalMockMvc halMockMvc;
   
     @Test
     void test() {
       halMockMvc
          .follow("current-user")
          .get()
          .andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$.alias").value("jdoe"));
     }
   }
```